# Rails Functional test: how to test the count of an instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, functional-testing

In my controller_test, I would ilke to test `@items.count`, where `@items` is defined in the controller action.

I have tried:

```
assert_equal 2, assigns(:items).count   # -> 0
assert_equal 2, assigns(:items).size    # -> 0
assert_equal 2, assigns(:items).length  # -> 0
assert_equal 2, assigns(:items.count)   # -> error
```

How can I get the count, preferably short of defining a new instance variable in the controller?

Comment: Are you sure it's not reporting '0' correctly?

Comment: Just to ensure that the count is being reported correctly, assign another instance variable in the controller. `@items_count = @items.count` and in your test `assert_equal 2, assigns(:items_count)`